# Why attr('r') / attr('cx') / attr('cy') all work but attr('stroke') not?

Tags: jquery, svg

I am using jQuery+SVG

SVG Code:

```
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
   <circle class="circle" cx="150" cy="75" r="${r}" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-width="1"></circle>
</svg>
```

I have a circle and I can use these code to update the circle. the code is very simple:

```
$('.circle').attr('r', 100); // works
$('.circle').attr('cx', 20); // works
$('.circle').attr('cy', 5); // works
```

However, when I am trying:

```
$('.circle').attr('stroke', 'white'); // fails to change
$('.circle').attr('stroke'); // successfully returns the value
```

I can't set the value but I still can get the value.

So I have to use the native way to make it work:

```
$('.circle')[0].style.stroke='white';
```

Why some attributes can be modified by jQuery's `attr` while some can't? What's the pattern?

Comment: Depends on your SVG markup. If you've defined stroke as a style you manipulate it as a style, if it's an attribute, you manipulate it as an attribute.

Comment: Please add your SVG code...

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the updates. Yes, I finally found that `.css` works. But I didn't use style to define the markup. I put the `stroke` as an attribute inline. I have updated the original question.

Comment: Works fine for me, the stroke colour changes with jQuery attr.